# Android sqlite fetch anyone row in different groups

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having a table "example". In that table I am having 3 columns say name,id,dept. Here except dept other two is unique i.e,. records should not be repeated.

### name | id |dept

### a    |1   |electronics

### b    | 2  |electronics

### c    | 3  |information technology

### d    | 4  |information technology

### e    | 5  |mechanical

f    | 6  |mechanical

here i want to return

### name | id |dept

### a    |1   |electronics

### c    | 3  |information technology

### e    | 5  |mechanical

i tried with using distinct keyword but it returns nothing.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is the relation of these 3 rows that you want?

Comment: that 3 rows is my required output

Comment: No i mean what is same in these 3 rows?

Comment: *i tried with using distinct keyword* - show us your query

Comment: SELECT * FROM  example  WHERE dept= ("SELECT DISTINCT dept FROM example );

Comment: @karimkhan nothing is same in these 3 rows look the first table it contains 2 electronics,2 information technology and 2 mechanical i want to return only one of these with corresponding columns as shown in the second table

Comment: I now update my answer.

Comment: if I am not wrong, you actually want first row from each group ( where group is based on the department ) ? right ?

Comment: i want any one row not necessarily first row it may be second,third etc i am having more records i just show first two records of each department

Comment: @Karthik:first two or first one?

Comment: have a look at my second table it has all dept from first row

Answer (score 1):

I finally found answer to my question my senior helped me out instead of using distinct we have to use group by.Code is 
SELECT * FROM example GROUP BY dept;

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Distinct` keyword to perform that query. For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <column_name> FROM <table_name>;
```

If it returns nothing, you probably have some errors on your code or database.

Comment: that will only returs electronic,information technology,mechanical not as shown in second table

Answer (score 0):

you must define an additional column for your table that it has a same value for your required outputs. then you can select all from table that has value in new column. hope you know what i mean.

Comment: add a column to your table(something like number) and pass same value for rows that you want to return. this is example query: select (id,name,dept) from mytable where number='number'. and this returns what you want.

Comment: yes this returns records based on the number. For example if i pass 1 i.e,. select id,name,dept from mytable where number = 1 means it return the row which has number columns 1 the output is not same as my desired output